# Concurrency in java spring : @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

I am developing a java (spring/hibernate) application which is kind of a timed and quantity limited sale platform .i.e I have to sell only 1000 cards of a type in the time slot of 10am-11am. I get around 150 000 requests in around 3 seconds and I end up selling more than 1000 cards, sometimes 1150, sometimes 1300. It in turn leads to selling more items than the specified limits.

I think that my program is not able to handle the concurrency even though I have specified transactional constraints on my function on my function. How can I limit and ensure that each request reads the latest state from MySQL table and the limit of quantity is not breached.

The code structure:

```
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) FUNCTION() {  
    1.//check limit from DB();  
    2. //if limit is not breached, insert new item into the transaction table;  
    3. //Update user profile;   
}
```

Comment: Provided information is too little for us to identify problem and help. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Rizz. Can you please comment why my answer does not satisfy your requirements? In my view if you synchronize your function using one of the suggested techniques you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this but it all depends on how much time your database check and update take and how many JVMs run your application.
If it is only one JVM and your transaction is fast enough then you can always synchronize the top level call. Other ways would be to use an atomic lock.

If more than one JVM involved you can use more advanced locking mechanisms such as the ones provided by Hazelcast IMDG.

I am not sure about MySql but in Oracle you can easily lock a process at database level as well. As you can see plenty of options :-)